# How do I make Command Line prefix in C++

Tags: c++

So, I tried searching all over the web, how to make Command Line prefix, but can't find anything. What I mean by Command Line prefix, I mean `RandomPrefix arg1 arg2` in CMD/Terminal. For example: `node index.js`, **node** is Command Line prefix, `pip install blabla`, **pip** is command line prefix. Well, that's command line prefix for me at least.

Comment: you mean the name of the command itself, right?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: if the name of the command is in the $PATH somewhere and you have executable permissions it should work, otherwise you will need to say `./command arg arg2`

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages Should be passed as `argv[0]` to main as usual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't ask how to get Command Line arguments, I ask how to make Command Prefix/Name.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages I have no clue what you're asking about. You might want to elaborate your question better, and give a concise example why the code you have actually fails.

Comment: But the first command line argument is the way your program was called. So for `pip install blabla`, `argv[0]` is `pip`.

Comment: I"m re-tagging as [c++], not [c++-cli]. Since the asker didn't mention .Net, and did mention c++ explicitly, I'm assuming he was going for cli=command line interface, which is not what it stands for.

Comment: In Visual Studio and xCode, these are called "console applications." That may help with the googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating a little bit on Stephan's answer, if you have an executable (i.e., a `.exe`), you can create a "Command line prefix" by adding it to your `PATH` (in Windows). After that, whenever you're in your console (`cmd`), the program will be triggered when your write it's name (e.g. if your executable is `hello.exe`, then you'd execute it by typing `hello`), and you can pass arguments to it if the program at hand receives any arguments upon launch. For adding your executable to your `PATH`  in Windows 10: Press `Win+X`, then `Y`, then search for `Environment variables` and click the option that says `Edit environment variables for your account`. either in `System variables` or `User variables`, search for `Path`, click on `Edit` and add the location of the folder where your executable is.

If you're in Linux, you can add some alias for executing your program inside `.bashrc`: `alias <command>='<path_to_command>'`.

Comment: What about mac?

Comment: I think you do the same as in Linux but inside `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

The "Prefix" is actually the name of the executable, e.g. - for windows - a `myprog.exe` called through `myprog arg1 arg2`. You define the name of the executable when you link your program:

```
g++ main.cpp -o myprog
```